# Cats/kittens with lumps under their skin

Tags: cats, health, fleas, parasites

I have multiple cats ranging from 2 yrs old to 4 months old. They have all been treated for fleas and tape worms and are now flea free and on last worm treatment. My question is has anyone had cats that have lumps all over them under their skin with a white center? [image: lump with white center on hind leg]

Comment: Could just be skin tags. Did you ask the vet?

Comment: No the lumps are under their skin. Some are just a single lump and others are vein like meaning it feels like a swollen vein long and in a wavy pattern. I wonder if its their litter although I haven't change it to a different brand.

Comment: I have to ask the obvious, are you sure it is not a nipple?  Can not tell the what part of the cat this photo is of.

Comment: Yes I'm sure this is his hind leg its deffinetly not a nipple

Comment: Did you ever figure out what this was? My kitten is having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

It is a Sebaceous Cyst.

A sebaceous cyst is a blocked sebaceous gland. Sebaceous glands secrete sebum around hairs.The sebum helps to guard agaist infection.
(http://wagwalking.com/cat/condition/sebaceous-cysts)
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sebaceous_gland)